# How to print full path of a folder which is not current directory?

Tags: linux, terminal, directory

Need to print full path of a folder which is from terminal which is not the current directory. For example `/media/hardDrive/Music` folder has three sub-directories Album_1 Album_2 Album_3.

```
/media/hardDrive/Music $ ls
Album_1 Album_2 Album_3
```

Need a command (*CMD*) that prints full path of a given folder from the current directory without needing to append the directory to the output of `pwd`.

```
/media/hardDrive/Music $ CMD Album_1
/media/hardDrive/Music/Album_1
```

Comment: Why can't you use `pwd`?

Comment: `pwd` will print the current directory. Like in example, it will print `/media/hardDrive/Music/`. I need to print the subdirectories without changing current working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the command.
It can be done using `realpath`.

```
>/media/hardDrive/Music/ $ realpath Album_1
/media/hardDrive/Music/Album_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use find to achieve that. `realpath` may not exist on all the systems.

```
find $(pwd) -name "FILE_or_DIR_NAME"
```

Example:

```
$ cd ~
$ find $(pwd) -name "reports"
/home/tommy/reports
```

Comment: `find` is at least as problematic as `realpath`.  They are both defined in POSIX, but `find` is known to have multiple, slightly incompatible implementations.

Comment: But that simple syntax should be available widely. ``realpath`` may not be installed by default. At least it happens on one of my testing VMs

Comment: `find` is also resource intensive and potentially returns multiple results when there are more than one file with the same name.  There are better options, like Python/Perl one-liners.  `realpath` seems to be absent on macOS and some old Linux distros from a decade ago.  Otherwise, it's provided by `coreutils`, `busybox`, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD.